# Extracting different kinds of information from observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I currently have an observable array with an array of websites.

```
sites:['www.google.com', 'www.stackoverflow.com', 'www.apple.com']
```

i want to format this array so that it will contain the website address as well as website title so when for www.google.com it's title will just be Google. How will i have to restructure my array to save in the title so i can extract them appropriately so that on a view page i will have `Google` and its value is `www.google.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an object in place of a string for each URL:

```
sites: [ { title: "Google", value: "www.google.com" }, { ... }, { ... } ]
```

**Example Usage**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: sites">
    <h1 data-bind="text: title"></h1>
    <p data-bind="text: value"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome thanks! But i am having them displayed in an input field so if the user would want to edit it but for some reason the title and values are not showing up in the input boxes and not sure why - this is what i have:
 `<input data-bind="text:value" placeholder="Enter URL..." contenteditable/>` and i have another input for the title as well.

Comment: got it i used `textInput` in my data-bind and it worked great! Thanks!